# How do you use jqPlot methods?

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I have looked at their documentation and searched the interwebs, but I cannot seem to find any concrete examples of how to use a jqPlot method with simple JQuery plugin syntax.

The documentation in this area is exceptionally sparse. For instance, the documentation on 'destroy' is:

> ```
> this.destroy = function()
> ```
>
> Releases all resources occupied by the plot

And that's it. And it's pretty much par for the course. That is the extent of documentation.

So I've tried the basic: `$('selector').jqplot('destroy')` and some variations to that effect, but they do not work. For all of the methods, I get a `No data specified` error. I am not sure to what this refers. I have verified that the JQuery object I am making has the class `jqplot-target`, which presumably is what can handle the jqplot methods. Perhaps this is not the case.

I would greatly appreciate at least one clean, working example of calling a `jqPlot` method on an element that has been initialized by `jqPlot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can destroy the graph :
Example: [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6L8c9/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //This will create the graph
   var plot2 = $.jqplot ('chart2', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {
      // Give the plot a title.
      title: 'Plot With Options',
      axesDefaults: {
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
      },
      axes: {
        // options for each axis are specified in seperate option objects.
        xaxis: {
          label: "X Axis",
           pad: 0
        },
        yaxis: {
          label: "Y Axis"
        }
      }
    });

    //To destroy the graph created by the above code
    plot2.destroy();
});
```

Comment: So you have to have a javascript variable specifically pointing to the graph? There is no standard jquery plugin selector+method to do this?

Comment: i dont think so... that variable contains the objects to that particular graph. You can also do a jquery element selector for the graph element and remove the inner html in it. that would also destroy it for you.

Answer (score 1):

In short, jqPlot sucks. Use [Flot.](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

Comment: Yeah, working with Flot is a breath of fresh air. I am still hoping for an answer to the original question for people that don't have the option of using Flot, but if you have that option, you should probably go for it.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, jqPlot is just garbage. I'm pretty sure it's a dead project at this point. The latest version of IE they support is 8. The site looks exactly the same compared to when I was investigating plotting solutions earlier this year. Safe to say that nobody should be subjected to that.